# Zenoss need to get freespace threshold and alerts on windows "mount points"

Tags: windows-server-2008, snmp, wmi, zenoss

I have a WMI query that will give me all the data I need to do this but I can't figure out how to get this working in Zenoss. I know I need to set data points and a threshold, and optionaly a graph. The problem is examples of how to do this with WMI are few and very confusing. Could anyone atleast point me to documention on how to do this?

WMI Query(WQL):

"SELECT Caption, Capacity, Freespace FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter IS NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the WMI ZenPack installed within Zenoss? http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-3392

This ZenPack will allow you to create datapoints from WMI queries. When you add a new data point, the the drop down a type will be listed as WMI.

This will allow you to set the name space, for you query above its just root/cimv2

Then you can enter the query SELECT Caption, Capacity, Freespace FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter IS NULL

Caption,Capacity and Freespace become the data points you need to add...you can do this by highlighting the data source you just created then select the gear (Zenoss 3.x) select add data point...enter the name of the instance from you WMI query.

Let me know if you need more help and what version of zenoss your on.